# "ZipException duplicate entry" after upgrading to Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After upgrading yesterday I keep getting these Gradle Build errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     xxx/.../XxxActivity$1.class

It always happens for whatever class I'm working on, e.g. an Activity class.

It's super annoying since I have to clean the project before every build.

I am using: `Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5` and `gradle:2.0.0-alpha5`.

Comment: I upgraded to ``gradle:2.0.0-alpha6`` but that didn't help. I also filed a report here but it seems restricted: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199004

Comment: The bug was probably restricted because they are planning to fix in a future version of the plugin.  I'm not able to reproduce but if cleaning fixes you could make `build.dependsOn clean` then build will always clean the source but that kill instant on :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the newly released alpha8 for Android Studio and Gradle plugin resolves the issue.